# Why Apache and my sql were not started in xampp?

Tags: mysql, apache

Port 3306

17:52:47  [mysql] Port 3306 in use by "D:\project 3rd yr\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"!

17:52:47  [mysql] MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

17:52:47  [mysql] You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application

17:52:47  [mysql] or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Comment: you have probably another mysql/mariadb server installed, deinstall it, or edit the condiguration file and change the port and start both servers new

Comment: ...if you already have a MySQL installation, you can skip starting the one in xampp, and it will use the one that you already have.